# get the last data from mysql using group by

Tags: mysql

table schema

```
create table test (id int(10) , stat varchar(20) , regdt datetime);

insert into test values
(10001,'ON', '2020-06-29 01:00:00'),
(10002,'ON', '2020-06-29 02:00:00'),
(10003,'ON', '2020-06-29 03:00:00'),
(10003,'OFF','2020-06-29 04:00:00'),
(10004,'ON', '2020-06-29 05:00:00'),
(10004,'OFF','2020-06-29 06:00:00'),
(10004,'ON', '2020-06-29 07:00:00');
```

I want to take only the ones that end with 'ON' in the stat column.
So I want to find id that ends with 'ON'

Thanks!

```
id  stat    regdt
10001   ON  2020-06-29T01:00:00Z
10002   ON  2020-06-29T02:00:00Z
10004   ON  2020-06-29T07:00:00Z
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7c0f90/3

Comment: There are 5 rows where `stat = 'ON'` and 4 unique `id` columns within the group of `ON` stat. So how do you get your requirement to show only 3 rows

Comment: Specify **YOUR** MySQL version.

Comment: using mysql 5.7

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT test.*
FROM test
JOIN ( SELECT id, MAX(regdt) regdt
       FROM test
       GROUP BY id ) max_regdt USING (id, regdt)
WHERE test.stat = 'ON';
```

Subquery `max_regdt` gets last date for each id. Obtained value is used for to retrieve whole row from another copy of source table.

The query assumes that there is no row duplicates with the same `id` and `regdt` - if exists then all duplicated rows will be returned.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388802/should-we-teach-and-explain-or-just-answer-questions?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: thanks. strawberry !! It really helped a lot. Good luck to you.

Comment: @NicoHaase Added. Does this is enough?